# error 1193 al crear un procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: mysql

Hola compañeros estoy intentando crear este procedimiento pero hay algun error que no consigo encontrarlo, como he dicho en el titulo me da el error 1193 de mysql= Variable de sistema desconocida p_salida

```
bloque: BEGIN
 -- PK / UK
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1062
BEGIN
 ROLLBACK;
SET p_salida=-5;
END;

 -- FK
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1452
 BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
    SET p_salida=-6;
 END;

 DECLARE v_Direccion int;
 DECLARE v_CodUsuario int;

 If EXISTS (SELECT * From usuarios where Nombre = p_nombre and Apellido 
     = p_Apellido and Correo = p_correo and Contrasena=p_contrasena) THEN
    -- SET p_salida = -1;
    LEAVE bloque;
END IF;


 SELECT codDireccion into v_Direccion 
 From direcciones 
 Order by codDireccion 
 DESC LIMIT 1;

 SET v_Direccion = v_Direccion + 1;

SELECT codUsuario into v_CodUsuario 
From usuarios 
Order by codusuario
DESC LIMIT 1;

    SET v_CodUsuario = v_CodUsuario + 1;

  START TRANSACTION;

  INSERT Into direcciones (CodDireccion, CodigoPostal, Domicilio, Localidad, 
                           Provincia)
       VALUES (v_Direccion, p_CodPostal, 
              p_Domicilio,p_Localidad,p_Provincia);

    INSERT into Usuarios (Apellido, CodUsuario, Contrasena, Correo, 
                          Direccion,FechaNacimiento, nombre)
    VALUES (p_Apellido, v_CodUsuario, p_Contrasena, p_Correo, v_Direccion, 
            p_FechaNacimiento,p_nombre);

   COMMIT;
     SET p_salida = 1;

   END bloque
```

Comment: ¿Es `p_salida` una variable o de dónde viene?

Comment: Si, es una variable parametro output de tipo int